# C# loading partial images into memory

Tags: c#, image, textures

Say for example that you have a 30,000 x 30,000 image, but at any given time you would only need a specific section of it that is for example 512 x 512.

Is there a way (or framework) to iterate or query for the pixels you are looking for without having to load the entire image into memory first?

Comment: What format(s) do you need to support?

Comment: It doesnt really matter, I just want to store the image data and query for the data that I need. Some more extreme examples ive thought about was putting all the color data in a sqlite database and querying for the pixels I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Microsoft's DeepZoom.  A good primer is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/03/31/a-deepzoom-primer-explained-and-coded.aspx).

> DeepZoom accomplishes its goal by partitioning an image (or a
>   composition of images) into tiles.  While tiling the image, the
>   composer also creates a pyramid of lower resolution tiles for the
>   original composition.

[image]

You can download the DeepZoom composer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24819).

Also check out [OpenSeadragon](http://openseadragon.github.io/) for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Seems like a good possible solution, however, am I correct in understanding that it needs to run in silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If your image is a jpeg/png, when you load a part, all must be loaded (because of compression)
If the image is a bmp, you can create your own load, because is a disk bitmap.

My advice is to create separate images of 512x512 and load separately (it's what google maps do!)